# How to not have orders prefixed in Magento

Tags: magento

Usually when Magento orders get edited they get a prefix "-1 -2", right? So is it possible to edit the order and not have it prefixed? Basically keep original order number?

Answer (score 0):

The prefix represents the store it has been bought from. By default you can't change this but there are a number of 3rd party modules you can use such as this one:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-order-number-by-amasty.html